# django passing arguements in custom signals

Tags: python, django, django-signals

I have a custom signal function:

```
def notify_after_registration(sender, **kwargs):
    email_subject = 'Account confirmation'
    email_body = "Hey {}, thanks for signing up. To activate your account, click this link within \
        48hours http://127.0.0.1:8000/accounts/register_confirm/{}".format(username, activation_key)

    send_mail(email_subject, email_body, settings.EMAIL_HOST_USER,
        [email], fail_silently=False)


post_save.connect(notify_after_registration(sender), sender=User)
```

Here I am generating activation key from my view and saving it in different model.

Now how to pass this activation key here and username too.

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

This line is wrong:

```
post_save.connect(notify_after_registration(sender), sender=User)
```

you should not call your receiver function here when you are connecting it

you should do:

```
post_save.connect(notify_after_registration, sender=User)
```

`post_save` is a built-in Django signal so it will be sent automatically with the `sender` arg.

It's all in the docs:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/signals/#receiver-functions

Comment: I am generating this activation_key and username in  views. Is it just that I do post_save.connect(notify_after_registration, sender=User, activation_key='123', username='myuser') or should I call this function in views? Without calling how can I pass arguements to this function ?

Comment: sorry I have pasted wrong above, I will update. there shouldn't be any kwargs or calling at the point where you _connect_ the signal.  the args are given at the point where you _send_ the signal

Comment: you cannot pass additional arguments to the `post_save` signal... and you will not know the value of the activation key and username at the point that you _connect_ the receiver function (which should happen at import time, not inside a method)

Comment: instead your `notify_after_registration` will receive the instance that was just saved, the activation key and username should be attributes of the model instance

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the arguments as keyword arguments (`kwargs`) as `activation_key=...`, `username=...` and so on. The receiver takes them in the `kwargs`: `kwargs['activation_key']`, `kwargs['username']`.

Reference: [Django docs: Signals](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/signals/#receiver-functions).

EDIT: You do not call the function explicitly. You trigger the signal with the keywords whenever it is necessary and meaningful (after all it is a custom signal), and the framework calls the appropriate receivers passing the arguments appropriately.

Comment: should I call my notify_after_registration in my view and pass kwargs ??

Comment: i have a model and view and signal. i am generating keys from views. i want to send email when the user is registered with activation key. When user is created an email should be sent to the user. and my view should be called ...

Comment: I believe both anwsers answer your question.